# Does 'Kritik' always come with a negative touch?

Tags: meaning

I often read

```
Lob, Anregungen und Kritik erwünscht.
```

My question: is it necessary to differ between `Lob` and `Kritik`? Does `Kritik` not include `Lob`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Kritik" can be used in a neutral way, meaning "critique" as in "review":

> Ich habe eine Filmkritik geschrieben.

I read your quote with this meaning.

It can also be used meaning "negative" statements (arguably, still constructive ones), i.e. "criticism":

> Ich kritisiere seine Vorgehensweise.
>
> Immer kritisierst du nur an mir rum!

Except in cases with an explicit review context you should probably assume the latter meaning.

Comment: I agree that *Kritik* for itself is not bound to either a positive or a negative touch. But the vast majority will use it with a negative meaning. Getting a neutral or even positive meaning of *Kritik* across to a native-speaker is - except for very few cases - impossible

Comment: @marstato: When used alone, true. Combinations like "Filmkritik" or "konstruktive Kritik" -- telling you that you did something wrong, but not a bad thing (unlike "Gemotze") -- usually have positive connotation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes Kritik can be positive and negative. Yet Lob is only positive and Anregungen are similar to Kritik but more konstruktive Kritik.

So you have.

1. Lob --> encouragemnt
2. Anregungen --> encouragement + suggestions
3. Kritik --> critical dissection or analysis, with or without feedback/suggestion/encouragement

According to wikipedia Kritik = Beurteilung.

An Urteil (judgement) can be positive or negative.

So in German you use this phrase of "Lob, Anregungen, Kritik" to solicit all three forms of feedback. Logical Analysis (Kritik), Emotional Encouragement (Lob) and positive reinforcement / cooperation (Anregungen).

Wikipedia:

Kritik
Unter Kritik versteht man die **Beurteilung** eines Gegenstandes oder einer Handlung anhand von Maßstäben. Wie die Philosophin Anne-Barb Hertkorn ausgeführt hat, ist Kritik damit „eine Grundfunktion der denkenden Vernunft und wird, sofern sie auf das eigene Denken angewandt wird, ein Wesensmerkmal der auf Gültigkeit Anspruch erhebenden Urteilsbildung.“

Comment: Eine Filmkritik kann positiv oder negativ sein; wenn im Alltag jemand Kritik an etwas oder jemandem übt (jemanden kritisiert), ist das immer negativ.

Comment: @Robert: this is important. It should be an edit to the existing answer here, or (better) an own additional answer (preferably in English as the Q was asked in English).

Comment: Kritik im Alltag IMMER negativ? Nein definitiv nicht. Feedback geben wäre für mich eine Alternative zu Kritik üben. Wenn man sich kritsch mit etwas auseinandersetzt, dann ist das nicht immer negativ. Das bedeutet nur, das man es analysiert und nicht alles für bare Münze nimmt.

Comment: @DisplayName Es ist wichtig, zwischen "Kritik üben" und "kritisch auseinandersetzen" zu unterscheiden. Das erste ist im Sprachgebrauch so gut wie immer negativ, das zweite ist eher neutral.

Answer (score 2):

Lob = praise
Anregungen = comments or suggestions
Kritik = criticism

In German as in English, criticism in this case can be either completely negative, or it can be "constructive" criticism -- but it generally means you've done something wrong, or at least not as well as you might have.
Someone asking for criticism is probably asking for constructive criticism, but they still want to know what they did wrong. In this context, the positive connotations of "Kritik" would be there (in the sense that criticism can be constructive), albeit minimal.

If you want to understand "Kritik" in the sense of critical analysis, then it would include praise as well, but since "Kritik" also has another, less neutral meaning, I believe "Lob" is added to emphasize the fact that people also want to know what they did well.
In addition, it seems to be something of a preformulated "stock phrase" people can use when they want feedback on their work.